# Set the value and display property for jquery's autocomplete source

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got a remote source which does not return id and value or label. How can I use it as a source for jquery's autocomplete plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `source` a function that makes the AJAX request manually, and then performs some post-processing on the returned data:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: request,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var processedData = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    value: item._your_property, // Property you want to use for "value"
                    label: item._another_property // Property you want to use for "label"
                }
            });
            response(processedData);
        },
        error: function() {
            response([]);
        }
    });
}
```

Basically, use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) to turn the array you get back into an array of objects that the autocomplete widget supports.

For a working example, check out the [JSONP example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) on jQueryUI's demo page.